# Search function for multiple fields in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, search

I am making a Search function in PHP MySQL. Currently, my code is working but when trying to search by date, all content appear. It seems that the 2 fields aren't connected.

Please help. Thanks.

```
<?php
$query = $_GET['query']; 
$date = $_GET['date']; 

// gets value sent over search form


    $query = htmlspecialchars($query); 
    // changes characters used in html to their equivalents, for example: < to &gt;

    $query = mysql_real_escape_string($query);
    // makes sure nobody uses SQL injection



    $raw_results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tblArchive WHERE (Author LIKE '%".$query."%' OR Title LIKE '%".$query."%' or Content LIKE '%".$query."%' AND Date LIKE '%".$date."%')");


    if(mysql_num_rows($raw_results) > 0){ // if one or more rows are returned do following

        while($results = mysql_fetch_array($raw_results)){
        // $results = mysql_fetch_array($raw_results) puts data from database into array, while it's valid it does the loop

            echo "<p><h3>".$results['Title']."</h3>"."<h3>".$results['Author']."</h3>"."<h4>".$results['Date']."</h4>".$results['Content']."</p>";
            // posts results gotten from database(title and text) you can also show id ($results['id'])
        }

    }
    else{ // if there is no matching rows do following
        echo "No results";
    }
```

?>

Comment: I am not in to programming, sorry. Should I need to add code in the Select query?

Comment: Any particular reason for the `AND` condition for date? All others are `OR` condition

Comment: @asprin If you enter two conditions on the search form, it should only find items that satisfy both conditions, not just one.

Comment: @Barmar Yeh, I realized that after posting it

Answer (score 0):

```
    $raw_results = mysql_query(
"SELECT * FROM tblArchive 
WHERE (Author LIKE '%".$query."%' 
OR Title LIKE '%".$query."%' or Content LIKE '%".$query."%') 
AND (Date LIKE '%".$date."%')");
```

Please Try This Query It will work fine.

Comment: But that changes the query

Comment: The issue is that `AND` has higher precedence than `OR`. So in the original query, the date search was only being combined with the content search, not author or title.

Comment: when we use multiple or & and condition then or condition & and condition should be separate. is it working or not?

Answer (score 0):

```
     $get = 'SELECT * FROM tblArchive';

     if(!empty($query)){

     $get .= ' WHERE (Author LIKE '%".$query."%' OR Title LIKE '%".$query."%' or Content LIKE '%".$query."%' ';

    }

    if(!empty($date) && !empty($query)){

     $get .= " And Date LIKE '%".$date."%'";
     }
     else{

     $get .= " Where Date LIKE '%".$date."%'";
     }

    $result = mysql_query($get);
```